# how to use file system (fs) in angular 2

Tags: angular, filesystems, node.js-fs, fs-extra

In my angular 2 application, need to use file system for uploading large files to Amazon S3 server. But, I have problem in importing file system in my application. Please help to implement file system in my application.

My component.ts file

```
import { Component,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import * as fs from 'fs';
/* External Services */
import { ApiWebConfig } from '../../../core/config/app.config';

declare var $:any;
@Component({
  selector: 'content-uploadpart',
  templateUrl: './app/modules/uploadpartcontent.html'
})
export class ContentUploadPartComponent {
  constructor( private config:ApiWebConfig ) { }  
  uploadToAWS(file:any) {
    var buffer = fs.readFile() 
    console.log('buffer',buffer);
  }
  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

And my uploadpartcontent.html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 upload_part_wrap">
            <input #fileUpload (change)="uploadToAWS($event)" type="file" value="Browse" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Package.json file

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "e2e": "tsc && concurrently \"http-server -s\" \"protractor protractor.config.js\" --kill-others --success first",
    "lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "test": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "test-once": "tsc && karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.0",
    "@types/filesystem": "0.0.28",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.4",
    "aws-sdk": "2.14.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "fs-extra": "^2.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.36",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "typescript": "~2.0.10"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

and System.config.js goes as follow:

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
      'fs': 'npm:fs-extra/lib'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'fs': { 
        main: 'index.js', 
        defaultExtension: 'js' 
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

after running my project, i get this following error.

[Console Error after running the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxI7l.png)

Comment: You cannot use `fs` in the browser.

Comment: So, what should i use?

Comment: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: Thanks, But i need module import in angular 2

Comment: Did you get the solution ?? I need it badly.. Please post an answer if you see this comment